# Is the number of pageviews a variable or a random variable, in this specific case?

Tags: probability, statistics

I've seen this claim (or some other similar ones) many times

> the number of pageviews would be Poisson distributed.

When I think about it carefully, I realized that this kind of claim informs more than I thought.

firstly, the number of pageviews to a specific website between a specific duration is a variable other than a random variable. (please feel free to fix this if you disagree)

for example, the number of pageviews to math.stackexchange.com on 2019.01.01.

take this table from this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9b4b/a3ceef973ffa48e5d71a93eded2c12f7add8.pdf) as an example

[image]

per my understanding, each item of a statistic is a variable, such as the number of websites that #PVs is equal to 0.

and then, taking the entire row gets us a random variable, that is, the number of websites in the number of pageviews #PVs.

is my understanding right?

Comment: One can define a random variable by:  select a web page uniformly at random from the universe of web pages and compute its page views (however measured).

Comment: Well, I don't really understand the table...it looks like it somehow wraps around so that there are really only two rows?  In any case, my definition makes sense however you define the universe of pages.  If you want to use the ones counted by some table, do that.

Comment: It seems to me either you consider the accumulation of page views to be a random process or you don't. If you don't, you have a table of data about which you can state historical facts, but you have no way I know of to base a predictive model on it, so it basically tells you what happened on that day and nothing else. If you _do_ consider the process to be random, then page views in any interval is a random variable and the entire second row of your table is all random variables.

Comment: @lulu I've posted the original paper, [here it is](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9b4b/a3ceef973ffa48e5d71a93eded2c12f7add8.pdf) again. Would you like to take a look and tell whether my understanding is right or not?

Comment: @DavidK I start this talk on a basis of that table, measured on January 30, 2002, which seems to be not a random process, is it?

Comment: The viewpoint of the paper is clearly that the data **are** considered to be the outcomes of a random process. Otherwise all the talk of probability, correlation, and uncertainty would be nonsense.

Comment: Basically all observed quantities in the paper, including the entire second row of the table, would be treated as random variables. The distinction that is made is that the random variables are generally not **Poisson** random variables, even the variables that other researchers have treated as Poisson variables.

Comment: @DavidK As for "the random variables are generally not Poisson random variables, even the variables that other researchers have treated as Poisson variables", would you please give a particular example, such as some items in that table or other parts of that paper.

Comment: I don't know why you're asking me to find things for you that you already quoted yourself. Starting on the second line of the abstract: "From a theoretical point of view, the number of pageviews during a day should be Poisson distributed." So that number may be treated as a Poisson variable (in other research), but as explained later in the abstract, this paper uses other random distributions to model it. You might try reading the paper for additional details. Mind that the data in the paper is 17 years old already.